# php - Selecting random from array without repeating

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am working on page, that gives you (based on range input) random string from array. It works by form with post method, that goes to same website, where is that form. But I ran into problems. Mostly it gives same string, as it gave before, so I would like to somehow save key from array, and compare it to new randomly picked one. Problem is, that I am beginner, and I don't know how to do that. I would be really happy, if You could help me.

Current piece of code: ($vystup stands for output, $rageFactor is input from range, $rage0 - $rage4 are arrays containing strings)

```
$rageFactor = $_POST["rageFactor"];
if ($rageFactor == "0"){
$vystup = $rage0[array_rand($rage0)];
} else if ($rageFactor == "1"){
$vystup = $rage1[array_rand($rage1)];
} else if ($rageFactor == "2"){
$vystup = $rage2[array_rand($rage2)];
} else if ($rageFactor == "3"){
$vystup = $rage3[array_rand($rage3)];
}
```

Thanks :)

//edit1

```
$rage = array("rage0", "rage1", "rage2", "rage3");
$vystup = $rage[$rageFactor][array_rand($rage[$rageFactor])];
```

Comment: put the `$rage*` vars in an array `0-3 being the keys` then just do `$vystup = $rage[$rageFactor][array_rand($rage[$rageFactor])];`.. simplez

Comment: Clarification - so you have 4 ranges of numbers and the user should be able to choose a random value from one of the arrays. The user chooses which array to use based on a form input. In addition, the same value should not be returned more than once for each array?

Comment: I have 4 arrays filled with strings. User by range selects $rageFactor (number of array, to pick random string from), and it gives him random string from selected array. But sometimes (mostly) it gives him like 3 times same string, then another one, then 2 times another string, etc... I would like to at least eliminate that it gives him sometimes same strings. Right now I am trying Lawrence's tip.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone edit1 is like my code looks right now, but it keeps giving me back "r"...

Answer (score 0):

PHP has some features, sometimes unreadable, but avoid code duplication.

```
session_start();

$rageFactor = $_POST['rageFactor']; //rage number, for test use $rageFactor = rand(0,3);

$rage = getRage($rageFactor);

if(isset($_SESSION['rage'])) {
    while($rage == $_SESSION['rage']) {
        $rage = getRage($rageFactor);
    }
}

$_SESSION['rage'] = $rage;
echo $rage;

function getRage($rageFactor)
{
    $varName = 'rage'.$rageFactor;

    $rage0 = ['A','B','C'];
    $rage1 = ['D','E','F'];
    $rage2 = ['G','H',];
    $rage3 = ['I','J'];

    $vystup = $$varName[array_rand($$varName)];
    return $vystup;
}
```

The code uses a "dynamic variable" `$$varName`, that will be translated as `$rage0` or `$rage1`or ... at runtime.

It will display a random element, from a random `$rageX` array, depending on which `$rageFactor` input you have.

Of course, you can create a multidimension array named `$rage` instead of multiples variables. It will be a better way.

EDIT: solution using rage as array:

```
$rage = [
    ['A','B','C'],
    ['D','E','F'],
    ['G','H',],
    ['I','J']
];

$rageIndex = rand(0, count($rage));
echo $rage[$rageIndex][array_rand($rage[$rageIndex])];
```

Comment: It simplifies the code, but still it sometimes gives same string, as it gave before

Comment: And $rageFactor is obtained by POST from form.

Comment: What is the content of `$rageFactor`?

Comment: Oh, sorry for not defining that. It's value of range.

Comment: It's a number like 0, 1, 2 .. ? Just replace `$rageFactor = rand(0,3);` with `$rageFactor = $_POST['rageFactor'];`

Comment: Yes, that works and makes code easier, but that doesn't help me with that, that it repeats strings. Friend of mine said, that I should use session. The page picks string, saves it to session. When page picks again, it pick string and compares it to that one, that is saved in session. If it is same, pick new one, and compare again, if it is other than that one saved in session, set is as $vystup. Problem is, that I and even he, doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: I think I could understand you problem. Take a look at the edited answer. You could use session and compare with the previous value, until you got a new one.

Comment: That's how I wanted to do it, but I didn't know how... I've tried, but the code didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Going by one of your comments above that you've got an array of 4 strings, there's a nice easy way, just use shuffle() http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php on the array.

Comment: I have 4 arrays of strings. Number of strings is other in every array.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the rage ranges in the session, choose which range you want to use, grab a random element, and then remove that element from the session so it isn't used again. This will reset itself when the range in the session becomes empty.

```
<?php

session_start();

$source = [
    'rage1' => range(1, 10),
    'rage2' => range(11, 20),
    'rage3' => range(21, 30),
    'rage4' => range(31, 40),
];

foreach ($source as $name => $rage) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION[$name])|| empty($_SESSION[$name])) {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $rage;
    }
}

$whichOne = 'rage' . $_POST['rageFactor'];

$output = null;

if (isset($_SESSION[$whichOne]) && !empty($_SESSION[$whichOne])) {
    shuffle($_SESSION[$whichOne]);

    // array_pop is the key here. It removes the last element by reference.
    $output = array_pop($_SESSION[$whichOne]);
}

var_dump( $output );
```